# Rails Callback, My callback works as expected from the rails console but not from a running server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  validates :login, :email, presence: true

  before_validation :ensure_login_has_a_value

  private
    def ensure_login_has_a_value
      if login.nil?
        self.login = email unless email.blank?
      end
    end
end
```

When working from the rails console and I do  user=User.create(email: "admin@example.com") the login automatically updates to admin@example.com  however when I run the live server and create a user with using the web interface it says 1 error prohibited this user from being saved:
Login can't be blank.  How do I get it to auto update the login to the email from the web site as opposed to just the console

Comment: I suspect that the web interface is returning login as a zero-length string, so `login.nil?` is false. Probably you should use `login.blank?` as the condition for the callback

Comment: Thanks that worked.  I did yesterday in the rails console that 002 > "".nil?  => false.  That empty string is not nil

Comment: Only `nil` is `nil?`.